# how to create asp.net web service for android and sql server connectivity

Tags: android, asp.net, sql-server, web-services

I have to retrieve data from sql server and show in android app. I don't know how to create web service to get data from server i google alot but not get the relevent tutorial and guidance. 
Kindly provide any sample code for making web service in asp.net

Comment: The are many tutorials on the net that will show you step by step how to do this and how to call the webservice from an android app. I would start with one of these then come back if you have a particular problem.  Here is one with downloadable c# code http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/how-do-i/how-do-i-create-and-call-a-simple-web-service-in-aspnet

Comment: is the sql server connectivity covered in this video.